# Typesetting arabic with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, arabic

For typesetting arabic with LaTeX there are `arabtex` and `arabi`; 
for typesetting arabic with XeLaTeX there are `arabxetex` and `polyglossia`; 
but how to typeset arabic with LuaLaTeX, since neither of these packages/methods does not work? And there is definitely a way (with very nice results) as demonstrated in ["Fonts" papers (PDF)](http://www.luatex.org/talks/screen-luatex-fonts.pdf) from LuaTeX web page.

I've also found Khaled's [lualatex-package](https://github.com/khaledhosny/lualatex-arabic) package, but still no go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It does not really answer your question, but I ended up using `XeLaTeX` as I also required support for arab.

Comment: Do you know Graham Douglas' great LuaTeX blog? http://www.readytext.co.uk/?cat=12

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because some works is in progress specially for the bidi package, on the other hand I am waiting for some of luatex bidi bugs getting fixed. you can test things if you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{font-name}
\usepackage{bidi}
\pagedir TRT\pardir TRT\bodydir TRT\textdir TRT
\begin{document}
%your Arabic text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves part of the problem, i.e., direction of text. Unfortunately, direction applies to numbers too, making them wrong.

Comment: for that you can use Khaled Hosny's experimental luadirections package which implements uni-bidi.

Comment: Or I can use custom commands for numbers with corrected text directions. Again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, much appreciated.

Comment: Please can you add some comments to clear what each commend do?

Answer (score 13):

### Updated Answer (2017-12-28)

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont
    [Script=Arabic,     % to get correct arabic shaping
    Scale=1.2]          % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
        {Arial}     % whatever Arabic font you like

\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]     % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\n}         [1]     % for digits inside Arabic text
    {\bgroup\textdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\afootnote} [1]     % Arabic footnotes
    {\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}
\newenvironment{Arabic}     % Arabic paragraph
    {\textdir TRT\pardir TRT\arabicfont}{}

\begin{document}

English text ``\textarabic{جملة عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}'' with Arabic in
between. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned.

\begin{Arabic}
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين \n{١٢٣٤٥} فقرة عربية
محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين\afootnote{حاشية عربية.} فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

---

### Old Answer

Two days ago [Khaled Hosny](https://github.com/khaledhosny) sent me this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Junicode}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont
    [Script=Arabic,        % to get correct arabic shaping
     Scale=1.2]            % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
    {Scheherazade}         % whatever Arabic font you like

\newcommand{\textarabic}[1] % Arabic inside LTR
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\n}         [1] % for digits inside Arabic text
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\afootnote} [1] % Arabic footnotes
           {\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}
\newenvironment{Arabic}     % Arabic paragraph
           {\luatextextdir TRT\luatexpardir TRT\arabicfont}{}

\begin{document}

English text ``\textarabic{جملة عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}'' with Arabic in
between. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned.

\begin{Arabic}
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين \n{١٢٣٤٥} فقرة عربية
محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين\afootnote{حاشية عربية.} فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

This probably is as uptodate as it gets atm.

Comment: The definition of `\n` and so `\textarabic` is wrong. See implementation of `\LRE` and `\RLE` macros in `bidi` package.

Comment: @Simurgh12 I don't know whether you could really say that they are "wrong". I am not an expert on this but I thought that this solution actually does not use `bidi` and thus does not use the bidi-commands `\LRE` and `\RLE`. But, as I said, I don't know -- it just works perfectly.

Comment: @ClintEastwood: It does not work perfectly as you claim. For instance, try `\n{\verb|\Hello|}` with your given code/example above and see what happens. Also try `\LRE{\verb|\Hello|}` with bidi package in xelatex and see the results for yourself.

Comment: @Simurgh12: I tried both and got different sorts of error. In fact, a few weeks ago I tried to get bidi to work and failed. Thus, I was happy to receive the solution which I shared. Why don't you just tell us what you'd recommend? Couldn't you just give your answer to the initial question?

Comment: What is the error that you get with `bidi` package in xelatex? You are the first person saying bidi failed to work. I support user9783 answer.

Comment: @Simurgh12: Sorry, I was inaccurate. Maybe this is the reason: I did not try or use XeTeX. I work with LuaLaTeX and the solution above seems to be the only one working (and definitely is the only one which I could find)

Comment: I hope that you said that with honesty!

Comment: This might like to be updated so as to reflect the change in naming of `\luatextextdir` and `\luatexpardir `.