# LuaLatex and the "Oriental TeX Project" -- Scientific Arabic Typesetting

Tags: luatex, ledmac, arabic

Does anybody know something about the future of Arabic typesetting with LaTeX or LuaLaTeX? Do they develop tools and mechanisms for scientific typesetting of Arabic text? In other words: is it still worth the effort to work with packages like ledmac, ledpar or ledarab (or whatever) to typeset Arabic texts? Or - because theses packages are still maintained - will they be adjusted to the new developments. (AFAIK the basic file structures of ledmac are from 2005...)

What about the general implementation of Arabic into LaTeX and LuaLaTeX? If [Khaled Hosny](https://github.com/khaledhosny) hadn't helped me, I'd still be unable to typeset Arabic text.

I've been wondering about questions like these, since I've found [this document](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mk.pdf) (cf. chapter XIII) months ago but never any documentation nor news about progress or status or usability.

Comment: You seem to be conflating two independent issues.  `ledmac` and `ledpar` are packages specifically for preparing critical editions of texts with e.g. parallel texts, footnote apparatus etc. These aren't required nor used for normal Arabic typesetting, which simply requires Unicode source,  good RTL support and the appropriate fonts. At present XeLaTeX with the `polyglossia` package (which loads `fontspec` (for fonts) and `bidi` (for RTL)) does this very well.

Comment: Since you're aware of this question: [Typesetting Arabic with LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21065/2693) it's also not clear whether this question really matches to format of the site, as it's unlikely to have a very specific answer.

Comment: A specific answer one could give would be where to get information on the "Oriental TeX Project" or about any plans of further development.
Of course, typesetting Arabic text works and there may even be a documentation for XeLaTeX with polyglossia. For LuaLaTeX, there is nothing comparable, I could find. I feel a little bit left alone with the question whether or not I backed the wrong horse when I decided to write a scientific monograph (which is going to include an Arabic edition and translation) with LaTeX.

Comment: Regarding ledpar: of course they are not required, but they aren't suited for Arabic text either. It would be good to know if alternatives are in development.
I am sorry if I misunderstood the format of this site but it was worth a try.

Comment: Ok, so then perhaps you could make the question more specifically about typesetting Arabic critical editions rather than typesetting Arabic in general, if the inadequacies of `ledpar` etc. are at issue.

Comment: Anybody? Yes. Have you asked Idris Hamid?

Comment: how to get an orientalTex snapshot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There have been a couple of articles in TUGboat specifically on the Oriental TeX project, by Idris Hamid:

- [Oriental TeX: A new direction in scholarly complex-script typesetting](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88hamid.pdf)
- [Qur'ānic typography comes of age: Æsthetics, layering, and paragraph optimization in ConTeXt](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98hamid.pdf)

An article by Azzeddine Lazrek, [RyDArab — Typesetting Arabic mathematical expressions](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-2/tb81lazrek.pdf) is about a different project, but may also be of interest.

Other articles on related topics, including Arabic and LuaTeX, appear rather frequently in TUGboat and can be searched for in the [category index](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html).