# Starting point for getting more familiar with TeX/LaTex etc

Tags: tex-core, documentation, arabic, learning

**Background**: I've been using what *I* would call LaTex for ~4 yrs to typeset assignments, reports, essays and tutorial notes. I have been using "TexShop" (for Macs) - mostly because it was simple when I was first starting.

**Situation**: I was recently prompted to search out the possibility of using Tex/Latex/[Appropriate name here] to typeset Arabic, but have found that I am completely unable to understand any of the jargon or technical language, and so can't make any use of the documentation found here and elsewhere on the web. While I'm not exactly brimming with excitement at the prospect of reading hundreds of pages of technical details about the typesetting program I use, I really would like to be able to start to get a more sophisticated grasp of the topic.

**Question(s)**: **1)** where can I find an *accessible*, well-structured and accurate introduction to Tex/LaTex/ConTex etc. that would serve as a solid foundation for learning about more advanced features (e.g. typesetting in Arabic; adding La/Tex capabilities to a program, forum or website; generating technical images w/ Texs of all sorts; etc.)?

**Clarification**: I am very familiar with *typesetting in LaTex* (I've typed 100s of pages of math, with all the fixings), but I couldn't tell you what the difference between Tex and LaTex is or *what* ConTex is or any of the "Tex" story and how it fits together. So, as far as I can tell, the linked thread on "what intro book for LaTex would you recommend" (sry for imprecise quote, I can't view the title while writing this), for example, doesn't really address the question. This is meant as clarification, not criticism - thanks to all who have responded so far.

While it is a subjective question, I'd also be interested to know from those who answer the above:

**2)** if they would actually *recommend* heading down this road.

**3)** I also wondered if there was a community similar to this one that had assembled instructional *videos* or even problem sets on the topic?

Ps. I tried to add useful tags to this, but was not allowed; perhaps someone else with correct permissions could do so? e.g. "readings" "intro" "basics" "beginner" etc.

Comment: This is not a real answer, but I'm a lawyer and not a technican guy: I buy nearly any book on LaTeX, which is published in German, to support the authors, well, and myself. Reading an introduction for beginners (not the "Companion!"), just between 100 and 200 pages, is a sustainable investment!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please only ask _one_ question per post. Also, I'm quite sure your question No. 1 has been asked on here already, try searching for it.

Comment: @RaxAdaam Regarding your first question, I would suggest you read [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/10119). It is of course possible to typeset in arabic with TeX and friends, but I would warmly recommend you switch to XeLaTeX which can handle all system fonts. Have a look at the [first two answers to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12347/10119): they provide you with minimal working examples that you can just copy-paste. You may need TeXLive (not sure all of the packages are on MikTeX).

Comment: Your questions are far too difficult for me to answer. TUG is the natural place to search for written info: there is lots there on Arabic. I would suggest you watch [this video](http://river-valley.tv/oriental-tex-culturally-authentic-typesetting-of-the-quran/). It seems to me to be an excellent starting point.

Comment: @doncherry re: question #s - will do, but to be fair 1&2 really have to go together. re: #1 I _did_ search, repeatedly and came up with nothing. the tags "beginner" "intro" "readings" turned up nothing. even now, the related posts that show are not really that related.

Comment: @DJP Thank you for the link - in the first 5mins it is already over my head, but hopefully it will be a good 'in' once I get handle on the basic landscape of the Tex world.

Comment: @ienissei thanks for the links. As mentioned in the original post, I don't know what the differences are between LaTex, XeTex, ConTeX, MikTeX and TeXLive etc. So, practically, I don't know how to accept your invitation to use XeLaTeX - ! I tried running a couple of the examples on the linked page without luck and then noticed that TexShop had a drop-down menu that included "XeLaTeX" - but that didn't work either. I really would like to understand - which is why I tried to place the emphasis on learning 'bout these various things as opposed to _just_ getting the Arabic to render. Thanks!

Comment: @RaxAdaam [On the different engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13601/10119) and [on the different formats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36/10119). Could you tell me which error you saw in the console when running the first example with XeLaTeX? For instance I see "fontspec error: font-not-found" at line 11, because I don't have the right font, which isn't by default on macs. But if I replace `Scheerazade` with `Al Bayan` it works.

Comment: @RaxAdaam I understand that would want to get how it works rather than just be fed with something that does work, but really, XeLaTeX works like any LaTeX document except for the engine, the `fontspec` package (and here, `polyglossia` which is like `babel`). It allows you to write directly in UTF-8, so you can type in arabic characters without getting errors.

Comment: I would recommend [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes) for "well-structured and accurate introduction to Tex/LaTex/ConTex etc. that would serve as a solid foundation for learning about more advanced features".

Comment: @DJP _Thank you_ This looks very promising. If ever anyone hears of non text-based resources, I'd also be interested: feelin' like I spend my life reading documents online & a video / course structure would be a nice change of pace.

Comment: @ienissei I got the same error, but the switch to Al Bayan just created a document with empty rectangles in place of the Arabic script. I searched out other Arabic fonts included by default on Mac, but all of them give rectangles. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RaxAdaam Sorry, I am no expert of the Arabic Script. Maybe it is a font problem, and maybe not… Some people here have worked a lot with the Arabic script, perhaps you should try to formulate a question describing your problem and what you tried in order to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different issues raised in the question, and there is no single resource which covers all of them. For example, typesetting Arabic is a very different matter from understanding the difference between LaTeX and ConTeXt or how to generate web content in a TeX-based workflow. As such, you probably need to ask focussed questions on the issues you particularly want to work on.

Several of those may have been covered to some extent before. Possibly useful example questions:

- [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49)
- [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36)
- [Typesetting Arabic with LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21065)

Answer (score 0):

As for the Arabic typesetting, you can try the ledarab package, that is distributed together with ledmac.
As for a manual where you can find not just the difference between TeX and LaTeX and that goes from the most basic to the most advanced, try LaTeX from wikibooks.org: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX
Still, go on visiting this site. In the end you get used to the jargon.