# bidi's undefined environments in (my) LuaLaTeX system

Tags: luatex, arabic, right-to-left, bidi

I typeset Arabic text with `LuaLaTeX`. I am using the following definitions and it works nicely:

```
\newcommand{\arabtext}[1]       % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
```

(More expanded version [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46627/12277).)

A while ago, though, I've been told through a comment that ["[my] definition ... is wrong"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21065/typesetting-arabic-with-lualatex/46627#comment111224_46627) and that I might have a look at the `bidi`-package. Indeed I looked at it several times but never got it to work on my system. In fact, I can not even compile an example taken from the `bidi`-documentation itself:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{Arabic Typesetting}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\begin{RTL}
Anyone who reads Old and Middle English \LRE{Short LTR text} literary texts will be familiar with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfred's jewel embossed on the front cover.
\begin{LTR}
Anyone who reads Old and Middle English \RLE{Short RTL text} literary texts will be familiar with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfred's jewel embossed on the front cover.
\end{LTR}
\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

The only result is `LaTeX Error: Environment RTL undefined`.

Why is that so? is `bidi` incompatible with LuaLaTeX?

I am asking, because I do believe that bidi could be a better solution than mine offered above (because, e.g., `bidi` has many other feature such as RTL footnotes etc.) and would like to try and to use it.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation suggests `bidi` can be used with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg : my reading was that nothing suggests that it can't, either. Much more so, since the above mentioned comment that "[my] definition ... is wrong" (presumably written by the `bidi`-author himself?) IMHO seemed to justify the believe that it could be used with LuaLaTex.

Comment: General question of efficiency: Why do `documentations` of packages not by default declare on the first page by which engines and processing methods (TeX, LaTeX2e, LuaLaTeX, XeTeX, etc.) they can be used??

Comment: The definition of `\RTL` and `\endRTL` are in `xetex-bidi.def`. There is a `luatex-bidi.def` file that simply enables some LuaTeX primitives, but doesn't define anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bidi` is basically XeTeX-only: the author has moved his LuaTeX code to a (commercial) alternative. XeTeX and LuaTeX use different RTL models, so completely different approaches are needed at a low level. On the documentation side: this depends on the package author. I'd always include a test in the code, with appropriate warnings/errors, but not everyone does.

(The LaTeX3 team have recently been looking into this to try to abstract some interfaces, but that is very much 'work in progress'.)