# Change font type in arabtext

Tags: fonts, arabic

I wrote an Arabic paragraph

```
\begin{arabtext}
\begin{center}

\Large{\textbf{معادلةُ زُمْرةِ إعادة التقنين لنموذجيْ بينر المتعامدُ و المترابط
}}\\ \vspace{0.5cm}
\large{إعدادُ 
}\\
\large{\textbf{رامي خليل}}\\ \vspace{0.5cm}
\large{المشرفُ }\par
\large{\textbf{د. عز الدين سمير}}\vspace{0.5cm}
\Large{\textbf{ملخص}}\vspace{0.5cm} 
\end{center}
```

and I want to use a specific font (arabic transparent)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please complement your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. (And a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).)

Comment: you cannot change the font in `arabtex`. Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead. (see answer the answer below)

Answer (score 1):

If you use LuaLatex you can simply include each font you have installed on your computer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\arabicfontA
    [Script=Arabic,        % to get correct arabic shaping
     Scale=1.2]            % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
    {KacstOffice}         % whatever Arabic font you like


\newfontfamily\arabicfontB
    [Script=Arabic,        % to get correct arabic shaping
     Scale=1.2]            % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
    {Arial Unicode MS}         % whatever Arabic font you like


\newcommand{\textarabic}[1] % Arabic inside LTR
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfontA #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\textarabicB}[1] % Arabic inside LTR
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfontB #1\egroup}

\newcommand{\n}         [1] % for digits inside Arabic text
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newenvironment{Arabic}     % Arabic paragraph
           {\luatextextdir TRT\luatexpardir TRT\arabicfontA}{}

\begin{document}

English text ``\textarabic{جملة عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}'' with Arabic in
between. Or again in a different font: \textarabicB{جملة عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}.

\begin{Arabic}
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين \n{١٢٣٤٥} فقرة عربية
محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
\textarabicB{اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى}
اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

To compile this example use: "lualatex filename.tex".

Code partially taken form this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46627/16071 post.