# multilingual table content

Tags: tables, languages

I want to introduce table that has multilingual content which are (Arabic, English, Vietnamese and Armenian) as the following figure

[image: this]

Any idea how to produce that

UPDATE:

code used to produced table

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,vietnam]{babel}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{document}



% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Bigraph& Arabic & Vietnamese & Armenian & English & English\\
           & CCA   & HC    & HC    & Brown& LOB \\
    \hline
    1     & \<ال>    & là    & ու    & th    & th \\
    \hline
    2     & \<لم>   &  ên   & ան    & he    & he \\
    \hline
    3     & \<ية>   & th    & եր    & in    & in \\
    \hline
    4     & \<لا>    & ch    & ար    & er    & er \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please add a [code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your efforts, if any?

Comment: @Malipivo i could only add Arabic and English by using arabtex package

Comment: I see, so the real problem is how to load next fonts and use them to typeset Vietnamese and Armenian words. Oh yes, please, add small example, it is a starting point for the solvers, otherwise they must start from a scratch.

Comment: @Malipivo i have added MWE as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to typeset it without [`ArabTeX`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arabtex), I've used the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package and the [Code2000](http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm) font. It is hard to say if this is what you need, if case you must use `pdflatex`, there are some fonts for Armenian and Vietnamese. I processed it with `xelatex`.

Next option would be to prepare this table in a separate PDF file with `xelatex`, crop it and include it afterwards into the main TeX file processed by `pdflatex`.

```
%! xelatex mal-multilt.tex
% Code2000 font: http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
% for LuaLaTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21065/typesetting-arabic-with-lualatex
%\usepackage{luatextra}
%\usepackage{bidi}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Text before (Latin Modern).
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \setmainfont{Code2000}
  \def\arabic#1{{\setmainfont[Script=Arabic, Language=Arabic]{Amiri}#1}}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Bigraph& Arabic & Vietnamese & Armenian & English & English\\ & CCA   & HC    & HC    & Brown& LOB \\
    \hline
    1     & \arabic{ال}    & là    & ու    & th    & th \\
    \hline
    2     & \arabic{لم}   &  ên   & ան    & he    & he \\
    \hline
    3     & \arabic{ية}   & th    & եր    & in    & in \\
    \hline
    4     & \arabic{لا}   & ch    & ար    & er    & er \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
Text after (LM).
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]