# What is better to use when writing a thesis in arabic, Babel or Polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, babel, polyglossia, arabic

What is better to use when writing a thesis in Arabic, Babel or Polyglossia, my text will contain bibliography,table of contents and glossaries in both English and Arabic.

Comment: I think, this is all you need:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46627/12277

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482396/decide-between-polyglossia-and-babel-for-lualatex-in-2019 . See examples with babel in https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/master/samples .

Comment: I'm going with Babel for now and see how everything goes thanks to ClintEastwood and Mr. Bezos.